# NameError (uninitialized constant ...) in spree gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

i define a controller in :
spree/admin/payment_members_controller.rb

```
module Spree
  module Admin
    class PaymentMembersController < ResourceController
      def index
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

in file config/routes

```
Spree::Core::Engine.routes.append do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :payment_members
  end
end
```

routes :

```
admin_payment_members_path  GET  /admin/payment_members(.:format)   spree/admin/payment_members#index
                            POST /admin/payment_members(.:format)   spree/admin/payment_members#create
new_admin_payment_member_path   GET /admin/payment_members/new(.:format)    spree/admin/payment_members#new
edit_admin_payment_member_path  GET /admin/payment_members/:id/edit(.:format)   spree/admin/payment_members#edit
admin_payment_member_path   GET /admin/payment_members/:id(.:format)    spree/admin/payment_members#show
                            PATCH   /admin/payment_members/:id(.:format)    spree/admin/payment_members#update
```

when i get to url "http://localhost:3000/admin/payment_members" (index) in browser :
in console :

```
Processing by Spree::Admin::PaymentMembersController#index as HTML
NameError (uninitialized constant Spree::PaymentMember):
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:253:in `const_get'
  activesupport (4.1.6) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:253:in `block in constantize'
  ..........
```

pls show me,  how to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

It's trying to [load the resource](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/backend/app/controllers/spree/admin/resource_controller.rb#L131-L149) based on the controller name you have using `before_filter` in `ResourceController`. Have you created `Spree:: PaymentMember`?

My suggestion is you either create the `Spree::PaymentMember`(app/models/spree/payment_member.rb) or override the `load_resource` method in your `PaymentMembersController`.